# Multiple Tab section in one page HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I created tabs in html page based on the code on this page.
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp

```
<h1>First Tab</h1>
<div class="w3-light-grey">
<a class="codebtn w3-dark-grey" onclick="openCode(event, 'TabA1')" id="myLink">Tab A1</a>
<a class="codebtn" onclick="openCode(event, 'TabA2')">Tab A2</a>
</div>

<div id="TabA1" class="code">
<pre><code class="language-sh" data-lang="sh">
Code Here
Code Here
Code Here
</code></pre>
</div>

<div id="TabA2" class="code" style="display:none">
<pre><code class="language-sh" data-lang="sh">
More Code
More Code
More Code
</code></pre>
</div>
<h2>Second Tab</h2>
<div class="w3-light-grey">
<a class="codebtn w3-dark-grey" onclick="openCode(event, 'TabB1')" id="myLink">Tab B1</a>
<a class="codebtn" onclick="openCode(event, 'TabB2')">Tab B2</a>
</div>

<div id="TabB1" class="code">
<pre><code class="language-sh" data-lang="sh">
Another Tab Contents
Another Tab Contents
Another Tab Contents
</code></pre>
</div>

<div id="TabB2" class="code" style="display:none">
<pre><code class="language-sh" data-lang="sh">
2nd Tab
2nd Tab
2nd Tab
</code></pre>
</div>
```

It works if I have only 1 tab section, but if I have 2 or more, there's a problem.
When I click one of the tab of the 1st tab section, it affects all tab section as you can see here.
https://codepen.io/mochi777/pen/YzOaoML

First Tab and Second Tab should be independent. When I load the page, it displays fine. When I click "Tab A2" the contents of Tab B1 and B2 disappears.
What is the best way to fix this besides creating a separate javascript?

When I click "Tab A2", Tab B1 and B2 shouldn't be affected. I know I can change the class and create a separate javascript will solve this problem but if I have many tab table it will be a problem. I'm looking for a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance your code doesn't differentiate between the 'tab sets', so when you open one, you close all others (including those from other sets).

You can remedy this by making some kind of filter, saying "only remove *this* set".

That can be of course accomplished in a plethora of ways, the most obvious that come to mind are e.g.:

- when opening a tab, close all tabs wrapped in the same wrapper div

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('button.tab-btn')
  .forEach(node => node.addEventListener('click', showTab));

function showTab(event) {
  const targetTabId = event.target.getAttribute('data-target');
  const targetTab = document.getElementById(targetTabId);
  const tabSetGroup = targetTab.parentElement.querySelectorAll('div');
  
  // hide all tabs in the same wrapper as target
  tabSetGroup.forEach(tab => tab.style.display = 'none');
  // show only target
  targetTab.style.display = '';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="tab-btn" data-target="tab-a1">Tab A.1</button>
  <button class="tab-btn" data-target="tab-a2">Tab A.2</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="tab-a1">Content A.1</div>
  <div id="tab-a2" style="display:none">Content A.2</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="tab-btn" data-target="tab-b1">Tab B.1</button>
  <button class="tab-btn" data-target="tab-b2">Tab B.2</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="tab-b1">Content B.1</div>
  <div id="tab-b2" style="display:none">Content B.2</div>
</div>
```

- add some kind of attribute to each tab which says which group does it belong to. Then look at it when opening a tab, and close all other tabs with the same tag value.

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('button.tab-btn')
  .forEach(node => node.addEventListener('click', showTab));

function showTab(event) {
  const targetTabId = event.target.getAttribute('data-target');
  const targetTab = document.getElementById(targetTabId);
  
  const targetTabSet = targetTab.getAttribute('data-set');
  const tabSetGroup = document
    .querySelectorAll(`div[data-set="${targetTabSet}"]`);
  
  // hide all tabs in the same wrapper as target
  tabSetGroup.forEach(tab => tab.style.display = 'none');
  // show only target
  targetTab.style.display = '';
}
```

```html
<button class="tab-btn" data-target="tab-a1">Tab A.1</button>
<button class="tab-btn" data-target="tab-a2">Tab A.2</button>

<div id="tab-a1" data-set="1">Content A.1</div>
<div id="tab-a2" data-set="1" style="display:none">Content A.2</div>

<button class="tab-btn" data-target="tab-b1">Tab B.1</button>
<button class="tab-btn" data-target="tab-b2">Tab B.2</button>

<div id="tab-b1" data-set="2">Content B.1</div>
<div id="tab-b2" data-set="2" style="display:none">Content B.2</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to figure it out. https://codepen.io/mochi777/pen/RwYJVma